# How do I read the data sent from this simulator?

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I'm required to make a 'height sensing subsystem' to read the data sent from a moonlander by making a UDP protocol. The client is already set up for me, and is a 64bit executable on linux run by using ./simulator. So I need to make the UDP server in linux to connect with the client.

The client sends readings from many subsystems in the moonlander, but I only need to read one of them, which is the laser altimeter reading that corresponds to the a type specified by 0xaa01, there are other types such as 0xaa##, and 0xff##, but those correspond to different subsystems of the moonlander I assume. The data sent from the ./simulator file is sent through the type, which I then need to decode to find if its the laser altimeter, and then I need to decode the values to convert into distance to find when the moonlander has touched down. I need to read the time first, which has a size of 4 bytes and is an unsigned 32 bit integer, and the laser altimeter reading is 3 unsigned 16-bit integers that correspond to 3 different measurements (as there are 3 different sensors on the altimeter, max height of 1000m, convert by dividing by 65.535 which is UINT16_MAX, and multiplying by 100 to convert to cm). I need to then take those readings, convert them into height, and then acknowledge that we've landed once we've hit 40cm away from the ground.

How do I read the data from the ./simulator file? Below is my code in python, and the output in a linux terminal. I can see that this is in hexadecimal format, but how do I convert this to read into actual numbers?

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 12778

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                      socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(8192) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print("received message: %s" % data)


output:

received message: b'\xff\x06\x13\x81(6iF~\xecB<\x951v\xe5\xebr\xd1\xf0r\x91'
received message: b'\xff\x05\x13\x81(6\x06\xef\x06\xfa^\x00\x08O'
received message: b'\xaa\x08\x13\x81(6\xef.\x10@\xba[\x95_-\x0c\xa8\xacD{\xad:\xca\x8c\x14\xc5\xc5\x8c\x84\xdd1Ui\xa5\xf5\xf1\xd4\x98\xc7\xe1\x02R\x11;\xf6\xff{\xd8\x0b\x9b\xae\xe9\x8f\x12)\x08\xe7\xcf|\x13>\xa4\xe4\xe9X\r\xf6\x87.\xfcmc\x06UP#\x89Y\x7f"f=e\x81\x88\xb2&\xcfl\xd7\xbb/ p\x1a\x1f\x1e\xaa\x88\x82\xb1\x82<\xec`\xed\x1c\x86\x1bM)\xef\n\xba|\xa7\xc8\xa6\x86\xa0\\\x13\xab\xda\xeb]\x1435]\x8a\'\x1a\xba'
received message: b'\xff\x01\x13\x81(6Ydo\x03\xadJ\xdc7\xb8\x05\xa0-'
received message: b'\xaa\x10\x13\x81(7d\x805wF\x90\xf2\x9c bq'
received message: b'\xff\x02\x13\x81(6\xa2\xb0\xe5\x94'
received message: b'\xaa\x12\x13\x81(7=\x9f\xea\xe9\xc3\x94\xf0\x82.\x9epWNn\xa0\x8c\xd3\xa2\x99\x08#\xc8\xeb\xb0_#r\x0b\xb8\xdb\xeeZ'
received message: b'\xaa\x01\x13\x81(6\x00\r\x00\x0f\x00\x0e'
```

All of the output except the last one correspond to different subsystems in the moonlander, so we don't need those. All I need is the last one. How do I read data? Some things about the data:

1. It is sent through big endian form through: type (2 bytes) --> time (4 bytes) --> payload data (0-4096 bytes)
2. Am I reading this correctly? ''\xaa\x01\x13\x81(6\x00\r\x00\x0f\x00\x0e'', I know that (xaa\x01) are the first 2 bytes that correspond to the type, the next 4 bytes, (x13\x81(6) (not sure why that isnt 4 different data points), and then the other 6 correspond to 3 different 2 16 bit integers which are measurements from the laser altimeter.

How do I convert this hexadecimal data format into real information I can then use to detect when the moonlander has indeed landed?

Comment: If it helps clear it up: when you're printing `b''` it prints printable ascii instead of hex when it can. One of the modules you can use to read binary data like this is `struct`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need a way of determining which message is the one you want to process. I assumed here that `b'\xaa\x01'` is the identifier for your message.

So if I understand you correctly,

```
while True:
    ...
    if not data.startswith(b'\xaa\x01'):
        continue
    else:
        num_values = (len(data) - 6) // 2
        values = struct.unpack('>' + 'h' * num_values, data[6:])
```

Essentially ignore every message that doesn't start with specific bytes in the given order. Then figure number of values you have by looking at the length of the message after `type` and `time` (6 bytes). Use struct to read them.

Note: `'>'` is means Big-Endian and `'h'` is signed short (2 bytes integer). Refer to `struct` documentation for more information.

Comment: Is there any way to parse the data as a byte stream rather than through a string like in the above example?

Comment: @ayoubster `b'\xaa\x01'` is a *byte string*.  It's a straightforward way to work with data bytes.  You could also say `bytes([0xAA, 0x01])` but it means the same thing.  `struct.unpack('>3H', data[6:])` will return the 3 16-bit integers.